# Excel Countif Not equal to string length of zero

Tags: excel, countif

I have a formula an iferror formula that puts in "" if an error occurs. This is a zero length string. I'd like to do a count if not equal to "".

```
=countif(A:A,<>"") 'is not a valid formulas
=countif(A:A,"<>") 'checks for actual blanks, not zero length strings
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a count for empty cells using:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A2:B5)
```

and subtract that value from the total.

Comment: That would work but it introduces an extra function. It seems like an oversight there is no way to do this in a single function.

Comment: Also, most excel functions do not diferentiate between empty strings and real blank cells, this is not easy to do

Answer (score 38):

Rather than using `COUNTBLANK` and subtracting from the total, you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"?*")
```

`?` is the single character wildcard.
`*` is the multiple character wildcard.
Combining these two, it will count if there are 1 or more characters.

Note that this works *only if the cells contains strings*, not numbers.

Comment: Fantastic suggestion. I wonder why things like this are not clearly explained in the online help.

Comment: THIS! I spent half the day today trying how to count zero-length strings as "blank"/ "empty" cells.

Comment: Does not appear to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 19):

You could perhaps use `SUMPRODUCT` since you have limited control over the range or criteria.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A:A)<>0))
```

`LEN(A:A)<>0` checks the length of the strings in the range `A:A` for whether they are 0 or not. Wrapping it in parens and putting `--` before it will convert `True` to 1 and `False` to `0`.

`SUMPRODUCT` then takes all the 1s and 0s and add them up.